# How to launch bash script on Raspberry Pi once it connects to a usb port?

Tags: python, bash, raspberry-pi, usb, raspberry-pi4

We are writing a script on a Raspberry Pi that automatically launches a bash script which runs some python scripts to collect info from a usb port.
Is there a solution to launch a bash script once it connects to a usb port?

Comment: If you need to detect when USB is plugged, you should read about udev rules in Linux, I hope this works for you: 
[udev rules in linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65891/how-to-execute-a-shellscript-when-i-plug-in-a-usb-device)

Comment: Also check out: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/